# CentOS 7 - yum install not working

Tags: centos, yum

Whenever I want to use command `yum install <packagename>` I get error:

> No package  available

For example,

```
[root@cpanel1 etc]# yum install autossh
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.t-2.net
 * extras: centos.t-2.net
 * updates: centos.t-2.net
No package autossh available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@cpanel1 etc]#
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: The package name is correct? if you search it with "yum search autossh" ?

Comment: @DarkVex `Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.t-2.net
 * extras: centos.t-2.net
 * updates: centos.t-2.net
No matches found`

Comment: @Rahul `Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.t-2.net
 * extras: centos.t-2.net
 * updates: centos.t-2.net
No packages marked for update
`

Comment: @Rahul `[root@cpanel1 ~]# yum upgrade
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.t-2.net
 * extras: centos.t-2.net
 * updates: centos.t-2.net
No packages marked for update
`

Comment: Check the files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` and make sure that they dont all have `enabled = 0` for each repo (there may be more than one per file). Before that do `yum clean all`, `yum clean metadata`

Comment: I used `cat <filename>` for each file in directory. They all include `enabled=0`.

Comment: Ok so you have all the repository disabled, for sure base and updates should have "enabled = 1"

Comment: @DarkVex Do you suggest to change that variable to have value `1` for each file?

Comment: @Kunok that's right, please change it and do `yum update`

Comment: @Rahul Yes I do.

Comment: I'm curious, why did you disable all your repos?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Someone else was installing the server and when I extended it, it only had cPanel & WHM and these weird config settings.

Comment: @Kunok: Hmm, guess someone's trying to lock it down then. It might be worth contacting them and finding out _why_, before you break everything. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These steps might help you,

1. `yum clean all` & `yum clean metadata`
2. Check the files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` and make sure that they don't all have `enabled = 0` for each repo (there may be more than one per file).
3. Finally you would be able to do `yum update` and search for desired packages.

Answer (score 9):

For CentOS/RHEL 7, autossh is no longer available in Repoforge repository. So you will need to build and compile it from the source, here is what you should do:

```
$ sudo yum install wget gcc make
$ wget http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/autossh-1.4e.tgz
$ tar -xf autossh-1.4e.tgz
$ cd autossh-1.4e
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well. In the meantime the original question (why yum doesn't install packages) was answered in the comments.

Comment: Don't build it from source. autossh.el7 is in EPEL. Install it from there, using `yum`.

Answer (score 5):

First install EPEL(Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux), then install your need packagename

```
$ yum -y install epel-release
$ yum -y install autossh
```

Answer (score 0):

`autossh` is also available with epel repo:

```
# mkdir /usr/src/epel && cd "$_"
# wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ihv epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm
# yum install autossh
```

Comment: if  rpm -ihv epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        package epel-release-7-10.noarch is already installed
How reinstall epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm?

Comment: If the repo is already existing, then you can try directly `yum install autossh`, if this is not working you may consider running `yum clean all` and trying again.

Comment: Simpler and more secure to `yum install epel-release` instead of wgetting a file over plain HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `autossh` package is available with the "epel" repository. To install it:

```
# mkdir /usr/src/epel && cd "$_"
# wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ihv epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm
# yum install autossh
```

This answer may be generalized for other packages in the "epel" distribution.

Comment: Please clarify what this is supposed to do and why it will solve the asker's problem. (Hint: It actually won't)

Answer (score 0):

You should also check `/etc/yum.conf` file or `/etc/yum.repos.d/` files to **make sure your package is not excluded** in yum.

```
exclude=apache* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* mariadb* da_* *ftp* exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot* dovecot*
```